# Change default CMakeLists.txt in CLion to include warnings

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

In CLion the default CMakeLists.txt sets the C++11 compiler flag only. I'd like to have warnings and the pedantic flag by default in all my projects.

This is by default

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

and I'd like to have this by default so I don't have to change it every time I create a new project

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic")
```

In the "Settings" - "File and Code Templates" I can change the C++ header/source template but not the CMakeLists.txt template. Is there any way I can change the default CMakeLists.txt template in CLion?

Comment: I saw that a feature request was opened https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-547

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that this cannot be overridden by editing the CmakeLists.txt!

Also I recommend making a backup copy of the file in question.

Go to the location where you've installed/unzipped CLion
and then

```
bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.2/Modules
```

and look for the file named "CMakeCXXInformation.cmake"

There just write/paste your flags following this model:

```
#This should be my default compiler flags
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -
Wshadow -Woverloaded-virtual -Winvalid-pch -Wcast-align -Wformat=2 -
Wformat-nonliteral -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -
Wmissing-include-dirs -Wredundant-decls -Wswitch-default")
```

You can write/paste this wherever you'd like - top/bottom of the file.

Save the file, reload you Cmake Project. Enjoy!

(The line with the compiler flags set in CmakeList.txt can be ignored/deleted)

**Probably a better solution:**

Since this doesn't seem to be supported by any of Intellij's products, I think the best solution, if you want the code to still be portable is to use a [live template] (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-templates.html)

I now use a live template called flags in which I just pasted my commonly used flags and also some other code tidbits. 
So whenever I am in CMakeLists.txt i can type flags and then press Tab to expand that text.
You could of course have many versions of flags and using live templates for them will ease the burden of having to type them individually every time.

Comment: This isn't an answer.  It doesn't even really qualify as a comment since it doesn't ask for more information or suggest improvements to the original question.  It should probably only be an upvote for the question.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't answering my question. With your solution the cmake settings are altered and not the default CMakeLists.txt changed. In this case I won't have the compiler flags enabled if I use the code on a different machine or somebody else is using it.

Comment: OP, are you expecting 'default' changes you make on one machine to 'magically' appear on another machine?   Such a magic event will not happen.