# How to enable all compiler warnings in CLion?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, clion

I want to see all compiler warnings in CLion. I don't want them treated as errors, but I want to inspect all of them.

How can I do this?

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286000/change-default-cmakelists-txt-in-clion-to-include-warnings

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to set compiler flag in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra")
```

Related question: [How to enable C++11 in CLion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317981/how-to-enable-c11-in-clion/26318013#26318013)

Answer (score 5):

For C:

```
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra")
```

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild your entire project.
Most compilers don't rebuild every file when you just press build, so you will only see warnings from files that were changed.

Comment: Doesn't work. I don't see anything. CLion only prints a percentage log of the files it has compiled so far.