# Error: can't allocate region after creating an object

Tags: c++, constructor, reference

I'm learning various details of OOP in C++ and wrote that code. The purpose of that code is to toy with ctor-initializers and learn how to inirialize a reference that is a class attribute.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Corgi {
    private:
        const string nickname;
        const string& rNickname;
    public:
        Corgi(const string& _nickname): nickname(nickname), rNickname(nickname) {}
};

int main() {
    Corgi buddy("buddy");
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles, however, I get this error message when it runs:

```
Project(1343,0x7fff7b2f2000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=140734714511360) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

I don't understand why I get this error message and how I can fix that. So, why do I get it and how to fix that?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: nickname(nickname) -> nickname(_nickname).

Comment: During compilation, you should at least get a warning for unused variable nickname. gcc even explicitly says: 'Corgi::nickname' is initialized with itself

Comment: @mfnx I use CLion and I can't see any warnings.

Comment: Concerning this, FYI: [SO: How to enable all compiler warnings in CLion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790467/how-to-enable-all-compiler-warnings-in-clion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
    Corgi(const string& _nickname): nickname(nickname), rNickname(nickname) {}
```

initializes member `nickname` with itself which is a problem as member `nickname` is at this point uninitialized.

A fix:

```cpp
    Corgi(const string& _nickname): nickname(_nickname), rNickname(nickname) {}
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2ead18e5ff87ac9)

---

I considered also this:

```cpp
    Corgi(const string& nickname): nickname(nickname), rNickname(nickname) {}
```

which will work for proper initialization of `Corgi::nickname` (due to the scope rules) but it introduces a new issue for `Corgi::rNickname` (which is now initialized with a reference to the constructor argument).

For this case, correct would be:

```cpp
    Corgi(const string& nickname): nickname(nickname), rNickname(this->nickname) {}
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2189e65f6348d1b0)