# Changing default cmakelists.txt in clion

Tags: c++, c, cmake, clion

If i want for example to add extra flags, or to change to the c compiler.
Is it even possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I want to change it for all my projects from now on by default

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286000/change-default-cmakelists-txt-in-clion-to-include-warnings)

Answer (score 0):

You can change almost all parameters of project in CLion. For example, to change c++ compiler you write:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER *path_to_your_compiler*)
```

You can find all required information in [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/documentation/) or just by properly googling what exactly you want.