# How can I change CMakeLists.txt in Clion generally int every project?

Tags: c, clion

I would like to have this code in every CMakeLists.txt which will be generated by every new poject: set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Werror -Wall"). Now I have to add this code to evey new project. Thanks for help everyone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default CMakeLists.txt in CLion to include warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286000/change-default-cmakelists-txt-in-clion-to-include-warnings)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking for, I think that you need to put your set statement before you call add_directory.

Comment: I program in C in Clion  and when I create a new project there is CMakelists.txt and .c file in which I make som code. In CMakelists.txt there I a can add some switches, for example -Wall, -Werror. I found this statement: set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Werror -Wall") which I have to add to CMakelists. txt in each new project. I want to add this statement to default CMakeList.txt so that I didnt have to add this statement to every new project.